# Django URLs NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've been trying to figure this out, but can't seem to catch my error.

In my Django 1.6 project I have two apps: `hold` and `control`

#### Project `urls.py`

```
url(r'^control/$', include('control.urls')),
```

#### App `control/urls.py`

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='control_home'),

#this doesn't work
url(r'^invite/$', views.control_invite, name='control_invite'),
```

#### Control `views.py`

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'control_index.html')


def control_invite(request):
    return render(request, 'control_invite.html')
```

#### Template `control_index.html`

```
<li class="active"><a href="{% url 'control_home' %}">Control</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'control_invite' %}">Invitations</a></li>
```

#### Error

```
Reverse for 'control_invite' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['control/$invite/$']
```

I get the same error in the shell. Not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: Hi, first I notice (didnt read to the end) is that you "closed" the regex in your urls.py, try url(r'^control/', include('control.urls')), without "$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `$` sign at the end of your main urls.py which means the pattern should end at `control/` and not allow any more sub-urls. Change it to this:

```
url(r'^control/', include('control.urls')),
```

Comment: Argh. There it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Project `urls.py` should be:

```
url(r'^control/', include('control.urls')),
```

There is no need for `$` (it means nothing comes after that).