# NoReverseMatch on Django URL when more than one present

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-urls

I have a table with a list of data values on it.  One of the columns contains a link to another page.  Sometimes there could be one link, sometimes two and sometimes n.

When there is only one link present the code works as expected, the pattern matches and it goes to the expected page.  Whenever there is more than one link present it fails.  It will still build the url correctly, I can see the full correct url in my search bar on my browser but I get a NoReverseMatch error.

Error:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'thelink' with arguments '('64f75fake8012b456073fake', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['thelink/(?P<table>[^/]+)/(?P<row>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

urls.py

```
path('thelink/<str:table>/<str:row>', views.thelink, name='thelink'),
```

html where it works and breaks:

```
<td>
    {% for table, row in data %}
    <a href="{% url 'thelink' table row %}" type="button" class="badge badge-info">
        link
    </a>&nbsp;
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```

Generated HTML from the html code:

Working:

```
<a href="/thelink/64f75fake8012b456073fake/64f75be82fakeb456073fake" type="button" class="badge badge-info">link</a>
```

Not Working:

```
<a href="/thelink/64f75fake8012b456073fake/64f75be82fakeb45603fake1" type="button" class="badge badge-info">link</a>
<a href="/thelink/64f75fake8012b456073fake/64f75be82fakeb45603fake2" type="button" class="badge badge-info">link</a>
<a href="/thelink/64f75fake8012b456073fake/64f75be82fakeb45603fake3" type="button" class="badge badge-info">link</a>
```

Note: I did alter the ids and links but you can assume those are correct.  I have also tried looking at these solution(s): [sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641948/django-urls-noreversematch), [sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865089/url-not-matching-url-pattern-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you described, it seems that the second argument `row` is not present. Which implies that there are `None` or `''`(missing) values in your data. Essentially, it breaks when trying to render:

```
<a href="{% url 'thelink' table '' %}" type="button" class="badge badge-info">
    link
</a>&nbsp;
```

So, I guess you could just `if check` before trying to reverse resolve something that does not exist:

```
<td>
    {% for table, row in data %}
        {% if row %}
            <a href="{% url 'thelink' table row %}" type="button" class="badge badge-info">
                link
            </a>&nbsp;
        {% else %}
            <p>No links here.</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```

### Another Way

Since you did not share any models nor views, I have no idea on how you are storing or accessing this data. Which, in any case still does not make much sense on the code you provided for your `template`.

Because there would be a nested list of `links` (either empty or with several values) per `data value`. If I understood correctly.

Here is an elegant way of implementing this by making use of the framework [relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

models.py

```py
class SomeTable(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)


class RelatedLink(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    some_table = models.ForeignKey(
        SomeTable, 
        related_name='links', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    data_values = SomeTable.objects.prefetch_related("links")
    return render(request, "index.html", {"data_values": data_values})
```

index.html

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Table</th>
        <th>Links</th>
    </tr>
    {% for table in data_values %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{table.id}}</td>
        {% if not table.links.all %}
        <td>
            No links here.
        </td>
        {% else %}
        <td>
            {% for link in table.links.all %}
                <a href="{% url 'thelink' table.id link.id %}" type="button" class="badge badge-info">
                    {{link.id}}
                </a>
            <br>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```